# Handling data from twitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, callback

I want to retrieve tweets and mentions from the twitter api. After doing this I want gather the tweets and mentions and store it in one json array. So far when I store both tweets and mentions, the system replaces the tweets in the object with the mentions?

```
jsonx = {};

var tweets = function(){
    client.get('search/tweets', {q:"@"+string.teamname, count:1},
        function (err,data){
            for(var index in data.statuses){
                var tweet = data.statuses[index];
                jsonx[index] = tweet

            }
        })
}


var mentions = function(){
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name:"@"+string.teamname, count:1},
        function(err,data) {
            for(var index in data){
                var tweet = data[index];
                jsonx[index] = tweet


            }

        })
}


var doSometing = function(tweets, mentions){
    if (string.checktweet1 == 'on'){
        tweets()
    }
    if (string.checkmentions1 == 'on'){
        mentions()
    }


}

doSometing(tweets,mentions)
```

Comment: Are the indexes in the for loops the same? If that's the case, one will override the other.

Comment: yes there are the same indexes in both loops @litel

Comment: You can add `tweets` and `mentions` as empty arrays inside `jsonx` when you assign it to an object up top. Then you can change the `jsonx[index] = tweet` assignments to  `jsonx.tweets[index] = tweets` `jsonx.mentions[index] = tweets`. And everything should work.

Comment: @litel thank you. Finally, I don't understand what you mean by adding tweets and mentions as empty arrays inside jsonx.

Comment: Essentially, you should have `jsonx = {tweets: [], mentions: []};` up top, so you are able to add the tweets and mentions without them overriding one another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111317/discussion-between-qwerty-ayyy-and-litel).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which is like merging to Objects (but in reality it creates a new Object). If you combine it with [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), you can do something like this...

```
let jsonx = {
  tweets: [],
  mentions: []
};

// ....

let tweet = data.statuses[index];

jsonx = Object.assign({}, jsonx, {
    tweets: jsonx.tweets.concat([tweet])
});
```

Your example involves **mutation** which is undesirable and leads to your mentions overriding tweets. This example is constantly creating a new object based on old data (same with `Array.concat` which creates a new array).

Comment: hi thanks for replying but I am a beginner and I am not sure how to adapt your solution to my problem